# Philosophy of physics - set theory

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I'm counting this as philosophy since it doesn't (as far as my research goes) seem to be an outright physics kind of claim. More like an intersection of philosophy of mathematics and philosophy of science/physics.

So I have found two articles that apply concepts from pure set theory, to physics questions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08505 which is about "Quantum Measurable Cardinals" (measurable cardinals being an (in)famously massive kind of number) and https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9909033 which shows (or purports to show) how to simplify/resolve some equations in physics using Cantor's theories.

My question is: how do these ideas/theories/programs/what-have-you, relate to the application of group theory in the Standard Model and its minimum extensions, or its simplified alternatives (e.g. string theory or causal-dynamical triangulation)? There seems to be a presumption (or methodological hypothesis?) about which abstract mathematical forms, are embedded/realized/w/e, in physical reality, as seen in e.g. E8 theory (which sounds like the claim that the E8 structure more or less **just is** a corresponding physical structure).

I'm also thinking of Max Tegmark's claim that *all* mathematical objects are counterparts (or embodiments or actualizations or what) of physical objects. His claim would perhaps go beyond the gauge-symmetry paradigm, granted, but still...

Comment: At a glance the second linked article does not look serious.

Comment: The first linked paper does not apply set theory to physics. It takes the "classical/quantum" analogy between elements and 1D subspaces and studies what analogs of measurable cardinals look like for the latter, a typical purely mathematical move. The second one concludes that "there may be physical systems containing real infinities" which " may perhaps be understood" using alephs one day. The "physical" part of it is completely disjoint from alephs and simply muses over divergent integrals in electromagnetism. So there is nothing to relate to SM and group theory, really.

Comment: I couldn't follow the first paper. In the second paper I didn't know the physics but the set theory as presented was at a very elementary level and somewhat uninformed. In the past I've looked around for papers linking physics to set theory and there isn't much out there. I don't think anyone's given enough thought to this problem. For example if the universe is actually infinite in any way, then questions like the axiom of choice or the Continuum hypothesis are subject to physical experiment. (continued ...)

Comment: (...) But no postdocs are applying for such grants! When they do, I'll know physicists are serious about infinity. Till then, my sense is that what physicists mean by infinity is very different than what mathematicians mean.

Comment: Some potential applications of higher set theory in physics were [discussed on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/279786/51484). From what I can tell the prospects look largely negative. The situation with concrete algebraic structures like E8 is very different, largely because unlike alephs they have computational import directly relevant to physical predictions.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your question? Group theory and set theory are not the same thing.  As to the attitude of the typical physicist to math, it is sadly characterized by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect.

Comment: I think Conifold has answered my question.

Comment: While E8 theories are more empirical in the sense of making physical predictions, it's probably worth noting that [E8 as a "theory of everything" has been debunked](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2658).

Comment: Group theory in the context of objects such as E8 is about symmetries. Emmy Noethe and others long ago pointed out that symmetries in physics represent conservation laws, time-symmetry being an obvious example. Yes group theory is typically regarded as a part of set theory, but that has nothing whatever to do with Cantor's huge numbers.